# Can black holes move at the speed of light? If so, what would its curvature look like?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes, photons, speed-of-light

This question has more to do with the curvature of moving bodies but I will first start with this.
If a photon has enough energy, then it could presumably become a black hole ([kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics))). I see no reason why the momentum of such a photon would not be conserved in its corresponding black hole. In such a case, I would expect the photon/black hole to continue moving at the speed of light. While this type of black hole may not be entirely practical, I do think it raises some interesting questions. For one, what would the spacetime around such a moving body look like, i.e. if a photon generating curvature moves at the speed of light, and the curvature itself moves at the speed of light, then wouldn't there be some sort of gravitational Doppler shift. Where the curvature in the direction of the moving photon would be bunched up while the curvature behind would look fairly normal. For that mater, EVERY photon and particle should have at least some velocity dependent curvature. When researching this I found there are some outstanding difficulties involved with simply moving bodies in GR.

So in short, can a black hole formed from a photon continue moving at the speed of light, and even if not, does anyone have any comments or papers discussing velocity dependent effects on curvature?

Comment: The second sentence is already dubious, could you reference some published work supporting that claim?

Comment: A kugelblitz can be formed from two or more photons intersecting, but not from a single photon.

Answer (score 1):

No, a black hole cannot travel at the speed of light. There are a number of reasons for this:

(1) the "no-hair" theorem says that any black hole can be completely described by its mass, angular momentum, and charge -- the original objects that formed the black hole don't matter. So even a black hole formed from radiation (kugelblitz) would have mass, and hence be subluminal.

(2) The speed of light is the same in all reference frames, so an object moving at the speed of light cannot "capture" a massive object in any meaningful sense -- the distance between the massive object and the massless one must eventually increase.

As for "velocity dependent" effects of curvature, remember that velocity is always relative, whereas curvature is absolute. So in general velocity isn't something you'd consider when looking into curvature. Two objects moving relative to one another do have an invariant kinetic energy relative to one another, and that can produce curvature, but no single massive object on its own has any meaningful "velocity". Light does have a well defined speed, but a single photon on its own does not have well defined momentum or energy (the momentum and energy are entirely frame dependent and may be arbitrarily small).